# WPF datagridview - geting outdated value when not pressing enter

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

i have a datagridview named mainEvents_sql with the following columns :

```
<DataGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event ID"  Binding="{Binding id}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="event name" Binding="{Binding name}" Width="*" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Update" x:Name="btnUpdate"
                        Click="btnUpdate_Click" CommandParameter="{Binding name}" >
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </<DataGrid.Columns >
```

i am trying to do an update button, i get the currect cell but it is the original and not with the new value, this is my btnUpdate event:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView selectedFile = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as DataRowView;
    if (mainEvents_sql.SelectedItems.Count > 0){
         String str = Convert.ToString(selectedFile.Row.ItemArray[1]);
         // update the DB with ADO .net
    }
}
```

str is the original value, how do i get the new value ?

EDIT:
I get the current value if the user press enter but not when he exit the cell by clicking on another item , how can i fix it ?

Comment: First: check that your object model implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Then, try to change Binding="{Binding name}" into Binding="{Binding name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" on your event name column.

Comment: Well I'm assuming that `mainEvent_sql` is your `DataGrid`, right? Why don't you just access its `SelectedItem` property? It should give you the current selected element.

Comment: @DHN doesn't work still the same problem , this is the new line i wrote:
System.Data.DataRowView selectedFile = (System.Data.DataRowView)mainEvents_sql.SelectedItem;

Comment: @michele what should i do when the event is fire ? i don't now how to access the changed object .

Comment: Id and name are properties of an object, aren't they? So when the event fired you can cast sender.DataContext to this object and access its properties. Since you implement InotifyPropertychanged and you set the binding as I suggest on the first comment, you will get the changed object.

Comment: there are not object but the columns name that i bind , i fixed it with:
        mainEvents_sql.CommitEdit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add (my datagrid).CommitEdit(); before i make changes ,another advantage is this way is update my source object only on save event so it supposed to be faster.